# Will Azure AD SCIM integration delete pre-existing users created directly into Snowflake?

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, scim

Hi I'm following the steps outline into: 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html

But I couldn't find any documentation explaining whether this user sync will affect my existing Snowflake users (the ones that have been created straight into Snowflake before the AD integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake support confirmed that the existing users are NOT affected by any SCIM integration and I tested it with success, nothing happens to the existing users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reference you are looking for is here:

See the note section of: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/scim-azure.html#enabling-snowflake-initiated-sso

> "By default, Azure AD users provisioned to Snowflake using SCIM are
>   not assigned a password in Snowflake. This means that if SAML SSO is
>   configured in Azure AD, users will authenticate to Snowflake using
>   SSO.
>
> SAML SSO is not a requirement if using SCIM to provision users and
>   groups from Azure AD to Snowflake. For additional options, see
>   Configure Azure AD single sign-on."

To enable Snowflake Initiated SSO
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-configure-snowflake.html#label-enable-snowflake-init-sso